# Can you please give me a Step by Step instructions to set up TFS in such a way that my team can access it from anywhere in the world?

Tags: tfs

Basically, Me and my team are working in the geographically dispersed location,My teammate is is in USA and I'm in India. I've Installed the TFS on my development machine (Windows Vista) and I want to my team to access the same exact project which i'm working on anytime,anywhere.

We dont have any funds to buy a hosting account or We dont have funds to create a VPN Account from the internet (my ISP doesnt provide me one...awwww).

Comment: Probably most suited for serverfault.com

Comment: some basics:

How are you connected to the internet?

scenario A: you are on a business LAN, you need to ask your admin to map a port on the public facing IP to a machine so that you can open TFS service to connections from the US.

scenario B: your connected through a personal internet connection, setup a dns mapping (www.dyndns.com) to your machine through your personal router or main machine.

without setting this up first nothing you do in TFS will make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

I don't run TFS, but this is more of an IT question than a TFS-specific one, I think.

My coworker showed me a trick that precludes the need for VPN, but is still secure.  You'll need to set up your firewall to route traffic from one of your WAN IPs to an internal server that allows SSH access.  These steps will be router and internal network-dependent.

Then download and install [PuTTY](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chiark.greenend.org.uk%2F~sgtatham%2Fputty%2Fdownload.html&ei=J5l8TPeRBJDEsAPY7c2CBw&usg=AFQjCNEawi7s0aRUeJP3qKnncgvPiSqZYA&sig2=X296sdJgI4XrGhPC2qm2_A) or [PortaPuTTY](http://lifehacker.com/162492/download-of-the-day-portaputty).  Set up a profile that points to your public WAN IP and SSH port, and also add SSH tunneling to route a port on your local computer to the TFS server IP and port.

Let's say you choose a local port of 12345 and your internal TFS server IP is 192.168.0.100 and the TFS port is 1234.  When you connect to TFS with PuTTY, instead of specifying its IP, you'll connect via localhost:12345.